# What to include for DependencyProperty so the IDE finds it?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(...)
```

I using

```
using using System.Windows;
```

and I have added a System.Windows as a project reference. But intellisense still says: "The type or namespace name 'DependencyProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So what using directive or reference do I miss? In C++, MSDN usually have a section such as "references" so I know what header to #include, but I'm not experienced with C# and MSDN keeps silent about what to include. Do I miss something fundamental? I know my code wouldn't work anyways but at least the IDE should find DependencyProperty at this point which in itself just a symbol in System.Windows, or it isn't?

Comment: Did you add a reference to [WindowsBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, you only need one "using":
`using System.Windows;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN for [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) clearly specifies

> Namespace:   System.Windows
> Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)

So you need to add reference to `WindowsBase.dll` and have `using System.Windows` in your CS file (or use full name `System.Windows.DependencyProperty`)

Comment: yes, I was on the overview page which listed examples without usings and references. I know where to look now.